How to animate all the objects in a collection using geometry nodes at once?
So, I would like to animate objects in such a way that the individual particles fly onto the plate and I would like to do it with geoetry nodes.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This would be way easier to do if the pins were all instances of one object, colored and placed by Geometry Nodes on another object (such as the placement grid).

You should not have multiple pin objects, just one pin that is hidden somewhere. Use Geometry Nodes on the placement grid, have it instance and color each pin on points at each hole, and do animated translations of the instances as desired. If you want them to fly in randomly, I would:

Start with a noise texture, maybe multiply it a bit.
Subtract an animated value from the noise texture color.
Run the resulting difference through a clipping node to keep it greater than or equal to zero.
Use the clipped result to displace the pin instances along their Z axis.


